# Eclipse Plugin Development programmatically create project outside of workspace

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, resources, workspace

Is there any way to programmatically create project, but in another location on disc than workspace location? I know, that Eclipse workspace is only logical container for project resources, and project can be placed elsewhere (it is possible to change location of built-in project templates), but how to do it from java code?

PS: I found some clue on ProjectDescription, but I can't obtain it in other way but this:

```
        IProjectDescription description = project.getDescription();
```

The trouble is, project have to be already created and opened, what involves project is placed in default location.

Answer (score 1):

You create a project using the description with something like:

```
IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();

// Get a reference to the new project - does NOT create it

IProject project = workspace.getRoot().getProject("project name");

// Create a description for the new project

IProjectDescription description = workspace.newProjectDescription(project.getName());
description.setLocationURI(location);
// TODO fill in other things in the description

// Actually create the project

project.create(description, progressMonitor);
```

Comment: Thanks for prompt newProjectDescription method.